# How do you make a fling gesture in the Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, onfling

I know this is not strictly a programming question, but even with all the "how to implement fling" questions I don't see the answer to this.

In the emulator how do you generate the actual fling?

I've tried LeftMouseDown + rapid mouse movement, but the results are inconsistent.

Comment: Ditto.  Mouse Down + Slide + Release.  But the results are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Confirmed:** It is LeftMouseDown + rapid mouse movement

Be sure to be over the control before the initial mouse down